# difference between __sizeof__ and sys.getsizeof()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Documentaion says :

```
   __sizeof__ :  size of object in memory, in bytes
   sys.getsizeof : Return the size of object in bytes
```

but when i tried displaying the size of an object both gives different output :

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

p = Person('vinay',30)
print(p.__sizeof__())
import sys
print(sys.getsizeof(p))
```

output that i got is

```
32
56
```

my question is which one should i consider?

Comment: Per DYZ: possible duplicate of [\_\_sizeof\_\_ not getting called by sys.getsizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051378/sizeof-not-getting-called-by-sys-getsizeof)

Comment: Don’t call `__magic methods__` yourself.  They’re there for the implementation to call *for* you, because it knows *how*.

Answer (score 0):

`__sizeof__()` does not take into account GC overhead

Comment: Answer looks OK, but maybe you could improve it with supporting information or with some background.

Comment: Loop up [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

Comment: General rule is to not give link answers as the link may change and then new comers having same problems will not be able to understand your answer. And if you want to link documentation as an answer, remember you don't have to give an answer to question.